# `\global\NewCommandCopy` instead of `\GlobalLetLtxMacro`?

Tags: grouping, latex-base

The new LATEX2ε kernel provides `\NewCommandCopy` (and `\Renew...` and `\Declare...` variants) which functions almost like `\LetLtxMacro` from the [letltxmacro package](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/letltxmacro).

Instead of `\GlobalLetLtxMacro` from letltxmacro, can `\global\NewCommandCopy` be used now?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `\global` prefix only works if it precedes (after macro expansion) a primitive TeX assignment:

- `\global<def>` where `<def>` is any among `\def`, `\edef`, `\gdef` or `\xdef`; in this case other prefixes among `\long`, `\outer` or `\protected` (with e-TeX) may sit between `\global` and `<def>`;
- `\global<register>`, where `<register>` can be any of `\count`, `\dimen`, `\skip`, `\muskip` or `\toks` or a symbolic name defined with `\countdef`, `\dimendef`, `\skipdef`, `\muskipdef` or `\toksdef` or any internal TeX register such as `\baselineskip` or `\everypar`.
- `\global\let`
- `\global\chardef` or `\global\mathchardef`
- `\global\box`

One cannot say `\global\newcommand`, for instance. Well, this does not trigger an error, but doesn't do what you might expect either. In some cases `\global\setlength` may work, but it's recommended not to use it.

The same is for `\NewCommandCopy`, because its expansion begins with `\declare@commandcopy` which in turn begins with

```
\edef\reserved@a{...}
```

so `\global` would be applied to `\edef` and globally define `\reserved@a`, which is not going to be very useful.

There is no “global” version of `\NewCommandCopy`: the idea is that such assignments should be done at the top level.

If you have use cases, you might open a feature request to the LaTeX team.

It's true that `letltxmacro` provides `\GlobalLetLtxMacro`, but I've never found any use for it. There are four packages that use it. However

- `tablefootnote` uses it at the top level;
- `lwarp-chemfig` uses it at the top level;
- `footnoterange` uses it in order to modify `\footnotemark` at the beginning the `footnoterange` and `footnoterange*` environments and also to restore the meaning at the end;
- `autonum` does a similar swapping as `foonoterange` for `\label` and `\\`.

I don't really see the need for doing such restoring, as the commands are modified inside environments, which form groups.