# Style fourier with esint

Tags: fourier, esint

I like the fourier package but I'd like to use integrals from esint package. I try to use esint after fourier and the \int and \oint have forms from esint, but \iint and \oiint have forms from fourier package, see example below. The same for triple integrals.

```
\documentclass[aps,notitlepage]{revtex4-2}
\usepackage{fourier} 
\usepackage{esint}
\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
    \int\hspace{2em}\oint\hspace{2em} \iint\hspace{2em}\oiint
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

I looked in fourier.sty and found that there are definitions for double and triple integrals but not for single. For this reason the definitions from esint.sty are used for single integlas. The question is - how can I redefine double and triple integrals by using esint.sty? Usually, the next style is redefining the definitions before. But why not in this case? In esint.sty the definition of \iint is following

```
\def\re@DeclareMathSymbol#1#2#3#4{%
    \let#1=\undefined
    \DeclareMathSymbol{#1}{#2}{#3}{#4}}
\DeclareSymbolFont{largesymbolsA}{U}{esint}{m}{n}
\re@DeclareMathSymbol{\intop}{\mathop}{largesymbolsA}{'001}
    \def\int{\intop\ilimits@}
\re@DeclareMathSymbol{\iintop}{\mathop}{largesymbolsA}{'003}
    \def\iint{\iintop\ilimits@}
```

In the fourier.sty

```
\DeclareSymbolFont{largesymbols}{FMX}{futm}{m}{n}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\iintop}{\mathop}{largesymbols}{206}
\def\iint{\DOTSI\iintop\ilimits@}
```

Answer (score 1):

In `fourier.sty` we see

```
\AtBeginDocument{\let\mathbb\math@bb %
\DeclareMathSymbol{\iintop}{\mathop}{largesymbols}{206}
  \DeclareMathSymbol{\iiintop}{\mathop}{largesymbols}{208}
  \DeclareMathSymbol{\oiintop}{\mathop}{largesymbols}{210}
  \DeclareMathSymbol{\oiiintop}{\mathop}{largesymbols}{212}
  \DeclareMathSymbol{\slashintop}{\mathop}{largesymbols}{214}
  \@ifpackageloaded{amsmath}{%
    \def\iint{\DOTSI\iintop\ilimits@}
    \def\iiint{\DOTSI\iiintop\ilimits@}
    \def\oiint{\DOTSI\oiintop\ilimits@}
    \def\oiiint{\DOTSI\oiiintop\ilimits@}
    \def\slashint{\DOTSI\slashintop\ilimits@}
  }{%
[...]
```

This means that `fourier` redefines the commands for double and triple integrals at begin document, hence overriding those done by `esint`. You have to undo this setting. Assuming you load also `amsmath` (you *should*, by the way),

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{fourier} 
\usepackage{esint}

\makeatletter
\NewCommandCopy\ESINT@iintop\iintop
\NewCommandCopy\ESINT@iiintop\iiintop
\NewCommandCopy\ESINT@oiintop\oiintop
\NewCommandCopy\ESINT@oiiintop\oiiintop
\AtBeginDocument{%
  \def\iint{\DOTSI\ESINT@iintop\ilimits@}
  \def\iiint{\DOTSI\ESINT@iiintop\ilimits@}
  \def\oiint{\DOTSI\ESINT@oiintop\ilimits@}
  \def\oiiint{\DOTSI\ESINT@oiiintop\ilimits@}
}
\makeatother


\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
    \int\hspace{2em}\oint\hspace{2em} \iint\hspace{2em}\oiint
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

[image]

I don't think you should use `fourier` with `revtex4-2`, which is thought for submissions to journals of the American Physical Society and they'll be unhappy if you do.

If you're with an older LaTeX release that doesn't have `\NewCommandCopy`, replace it with `\LetLtxMacro` after loading `\usepackage{letltxmacro}`.

Comment: It does not work and gives errors - 
Undefined control sequence \NewCommandCopy. I tried with revtex and with article styles. I use revtex with these styles for my own use, only. Revtex has the very useful option - it can group references under a single by using * option.

Comment: I do not understand why \NewCommandCopy gives an error. By using the discussion [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/661784/global-newcommandcopy-instead-of-globalletltxmacro) I changed \NewCommandCopy to  \LetLtxMacro and added \usepackage{letltxmacro} in the preamble. Now it works. But need more packages to load.

Comment: tex --version -> TeX 3.14159265 (TeX Live 2019/Debian) I guess that the problem connects with version texlive. [Here](https://www.latex-project.org/news/2020/09/01/latex-dev-2020-10-1c/) one notes "A \NewCommandCopy was added " in Main features of the final pre-release for 2020-10-01.

Comment: @nail Debian is lagging behind a lot. The `\LetLtxMacro` strategy for such outdated distributions is the right one.

Comment: I found this info (see my post above). Thank you a lot for this solution. But last question. The next package usually redefine the definitions made in packages loaded before. Why in this case I have to redefine manually?

Comment: @nail Because `fourier` redefines the double and triple integrals at begin document, so overriding the redefinitions of `esint`. I added a more detailed explanation and also the suggestion for older LaTeX releases.